# Simple way to display an existing Google Calendar in Rails and allow event booking without user sign in?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar, google-calendar-api

My client has me working on an Event booking/scheduling app in Rails. The user will come to the app's page, select an event and options, and then be displayed an existing Google Calendar that shows available dates and times.

Let's say they want to book `Face Painting` on `November 15, 2016` from `1pm to 5pm`, as an example.

I'm stuck here because my client **does not** want the user to sign in. So I think I'll have to use a `session_id` to (eventually) pass verified Stripe payment to Google Calendar and create an event on the existing Google Calendar.

I have it working up to the point where the user selects their `Event` and `:event_options`, but I don't know how to get the existing calendar events to show to the user and let them select their time/dates to finish booking.

Does anyone know the simplest solution to this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## **Perform Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority**

> In enterprise applications you may want to programmatically access users data without any manual authorization on their part. In Google Apps domains, the domain administrator can grant to third party applications domain-wide access to its users' data — this is referred as domain-wide delegation of authority. To delegate authority this way, domain administrators can use service accounts with OAuth 2.0.
>
> For additional detailed information, see [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Though it's not in ruby see this example tutorial by daimto [Google Calendar API with PHP – Service Account](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/)

For getting the events use [**`Events: list`**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

> Returns events on the specified calendar.

Then create a function to show a calendar like UI that will display the given list of events to the user.

Hope this helps!